# Vlookup or VBA on getting specific data out of many single cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, vlookup

I have a strange one.  I extract data from an application into an Excel spreadsheet to do some high-level analysis. I have one column, called History, and it can have numerous entries inside a single cell instead of a simple date etc. Here is an example: [image]

Here is another example

[image]

What I need is the first or earliest time stamp in the cell where it has Technical/other approvers added is below (highlighted). Said in a different way, the one that is at the very bottom.  I looked through a 3 dozen records and that appears to hold true.  There are times where it has only one entry with a time stamp and Technical/other approvers added below in the cell with no other data.   This is driving me crazy because it has the data I need by can’t get at it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the following should work.  The Regular Expression will return the **last** date in the cell (and it must be in the format you show) where the very **next** line starts with the phrase "*Technical/other approvers*"

```
Option Explicit
Function LastDate(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "[\s\S]+((?:\d{2}-){2}\d{4}\s(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}).*[\n\r]+Technical/other approvers.*"
    .ignorecase = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Global = False
    If RE.test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = RE.Execute(S)
        LastDate = MC(0).submatches(0)
    End If
End With

End Function
```

[image]

**EDIT**: (*per the suggestion of Raystafarian*)
The above code uses what is called *late-binding*.  If you are using this only on your own machine, *early-binding* would be preferable, as you then have the advantage of *Intellisense* when entering the code.  If it is going to be distributed, it may not be so simple as you would need to set references on all of the recipients computers.

Performance should be improved.  However, whether this is noticeable would depend on the size of your database.

Here is the code re-written to take advantage of early-binding.

```
Option Explicit
'Using Early Binding
'Set Reference (Tools/References) to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

Function LastDate2(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection

Set RE = New RegExp
With RE
    .Pattern = "[\s\S]+((?:\d{2}-){2}\d{4}\s(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}).*[\n\r]+Technical/other approvers.*"
    .ignorecase = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Global = False
    If RE.test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = RE.Execute(S)
        LastDate2 = MC(0).submatches(0)
    End If
End With

End Function
```

Comment: Make sure you have the regex library enabled too

Comment: @Raystafarian If by *enable* you mean *setting a reference*, there is no need with the code provided which uses *late-binding*.  I like *early binding* as it provides `Intellisense`, but it can be problematic on distributed code, unless you programmatically set it within the code.

Comment: True, but the performance will suffer with late binding, if it's more code than just this, in which case a `RegExp` would be better than an [`Object`]((https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcxd6b8.aspx)). Nothing *wrong* here - just better practice.

Comment: @Raystafarian I'll add a code segment demonstrating early binding.

Answer (score 0):

Something easy would be a loop, I prefer `for` loops but a `do until` might work better.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim searchRange As Range
Dim searchString As String
Dim cellValue As String
Dim myCell As Range
Dim foundCell As Range
Set searchRange = Range("A2:A10")
searchString = "Technical/other approvers"

For Each myCell In searchRange
    cellValue = myCell
    If InStr(cellValue, searchString) Then
        Set foundCell = myCell
        Exit For
    End If
Next
MsgBox "found at " & myCell.Address

Dim myTimeStamp As String
Dim endString As Long
endString = InStr(myCell, " - ")

myTimeStamp = Left(myCell, endString - 1)
MsgBox myTimeStamp

End Sub
```

Of course, if it were me I'd have

```
lastRow = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
dim i as long
for i = 1 to lastRow
  cellValue = cells(i,1)
  ...
```

Comment: First off - Thank you!  It is somewhat working.  This is what it is doing now.  the first and fourth are correct.  http://imgur.com/a/keoNc

Comment: I thought they were already in date order. The other answer is probably what you're looking for. @Ducatiduke